# Solr Sorting for String Literal - PatternReplaceFilterFactory

Tags: java, regex, sorting, solr

What is the regular expression for the following special characters in Solr.

## ,~,!,@,Double Quotes,Single Quote,Brackets,? and for every special characters.

My code is:

```
<fieldType name="Custom_sort" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingFirst="true" sortMissingLast="true" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(#|!|[0-9]|'|~|^|&quot;|[)]|[(])" replacement=""  replace="all" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

but this does not work.
How to write pattern for these special characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of handling for individual special characters use below, will remove all special characters except alphabets

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all" />
```

Why is the analyzer applied at query time, as you would use this as sort field and need to apply the analysis at index time ?

```
<fieldType name="Custom_sort" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingFirst="true" sortMissingLast="true" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```